# Mean correlation significance

Tags: r, correlation

My question may be kind of simple but I did not manage to find an answer myself. I have a correlation matrix and I'd like to compute the mean correlation within a group of variables and then test if it's significantly different from 0.

Let's say I have the following correlation matrix:
[image]

If I want to know the mean correlation between 1,2 and 5, how can I code it in R? Obviously this becomes a problem because my matrix is much larger and my groups are also larger and it's kind of long to find the mean manually for each landmark.

Thank you in advance.

Best,
Sérgio.

Comment: If you want R code you would be better off on a programming site. You could edit your question to emphasise the statistical issue though which if I understand you well relates to averaging non-independent correlations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but if you want the mean of three numbers, you can do

```
mean(c(1, 2))
```

In this case, to also get the numbers, you can select them with

```
corrs <- example_corrmat[c(1, 2, 2), c(2, 5, 1)]
mean(corrs)
```

This selects the three correlations between 1, 2 and 5 and then computes their mean.

Averaging correlations seems a bit weird to me (for example, a negative correlation and a positive correlation will cancel out), what do you want with this?

Comment: I have several clusters and I want to test them. I read the first step would be a Fisher's Z transformation of Pearson's R value. In this case, imagine that 1,2 and 5 are in the same cluster. I want to know the within-group mean correlation.